# Using cmd through C# to zip and unzip files problems

Tags: c#, zip, unzip, cmd

I've been using C# to execute cmd commands centred around zipping and unzipping files through the system.diagnostics.process class but have been encountering some difficulties:
while trying to zip or unzip some of the folders, the process does not complete the zip command and then stops to react to further commands. sometimes when that happens the zip files will appear after I have completely closed the program.

Please assit me thank you...

Comment: It is usually very helpful to post some code.

Comment: does it have to be zip? or are you just looking for compression?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, managed to solve on my own, used a different way to access the zip commands:

Comment: You should answer you own question. And accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed control over external processes can become very tricky. Is SharpZipLib not an option for you?

Comment: No, sorry I forgot to mention that in my current working environment 3rd party libraries are not an option!